# Does Corda support the tearing-off of individual fields within states of a transaction?

Tags: corda

I know that in Corda, you can tear-off the individual components of a transaction.

Can you also tear-off individual fields within a state? If not, are there plans to support this in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tear-offs in Corda are possible because transactions are represented using Merkle trees, with the transaction's components (states, commands...) as the leaves. This means that individual components can be "torn off", without it being possible to change the contents of what has been torn off after a signature has been applied.

As of Corda 3.2, it is not possible to tear off fields of individual states in the same way, since they are represented as fields of JVM objects.

Comment: Does this still apply to the latest Corda version (4.1)?

Comment: Yes, this has not changed as of 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

We can define an `individual field` of the `business model class` as `State` in Corda, then you can share the list of states as required by the counterparty.